# Google Directory API groups

Tags: python, google-api, google-directory-api

I am trying to use Google's admin directory API (with Google's python library).

I am able to list the users on the directory just fine, using some code like this:

```
results = client.users().list(customer='my_customer').execute()
```

However, those results do not include which groups the users are a member of.  Instead, it appears that once I have the list of users, I then have to make a call to get a list of groups:

```
results = client.groups().list(customer='my_customer').execute()
```

And then go through each group and call the "members" api to see which users are in a group:

```
results = client.members().list(groupKey='[group key]').execute()
```

Which means that I have to make a new request for every group.

It seems to be horribly inefficient.  There has to be a better way than this, and I'm just missing it.  What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better way than the one you described (yet?): Iterate over groups and get member list of each one.

I agree that is not the answer you want to read, but it is also the way we do maintenance over group members.

Answer (score 1):

The following method should be more efficient, although not 100% great :

For each user, call [the `groups.list` method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list) and pass the `userKey` parameter to specify that you only want groups who have user X as a member.

I'm not a Python developper, but it should look like this :

```
results = client.groups().list(customer='my_customer',userKey='user@domain.com').execute()
```

Comment: It actually seems like this would be less efficient, since there's bound to be more users than there is groups.  Querying each user for their group list is going to be more API requests than querying each group for the list of members.

Comment: I don't think `client.groups().list()` takes 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For each user:

results = client.groups().list(userKey=user,pageToken=None).execute()

where 'user' is the user's primary/alias email address or ID

This will return a page of groups the user is a member of, see:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list

Comment: See my comment on @David's answer.